# Upload file to server Android

Tags: php, android, rest, file-upload, httpurlconnection

I want to upload some mp3 files to my localhost server however I am not sure where I am going wrong. I think it is the `php` file, but here is my `php` file:

```
<?php
    $file_path = "/storage/emulated/0/sample.txt";
    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

This is my `java` code:

```
public class UploadFile extends Activity {
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    String serverResponseMessage;
    String uploadFileName;
    String uploadFilePath;
    String upLoadServerUri = null;
    ProgressBar loading;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.uploads);
        uploadFilePath = "/storage/emulated/0/";
        uploadFileName = "sample.txt";

        upLoadServerUri = "http://10.0.3.2/files/uploadfile.php";
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
        String fileName = sourceFileUri;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int code;

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            code = 0;
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                }
            });
        }
        else {
            try {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs

                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='uploaded_file';filename='"+fileName+"'"+lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                code = serverResponseCode;
                if (code==200) {
                    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                        }
                    });
                }
                serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got this code online and modified it for my purpose - but it is not working, but as I mentioned it could be the `php` file

Any help will really mean a lot (even a fix for this will let me eat and sleep properly)

Thanks

Comment: Don't just tell us it isn't working.. actually say what is happening instead. What have you tried to fix that problem? What happened when you did that?

Comment: Its the php file. I think it isnt doing anything. As in how do I send the file in the php file?

Comment: ***We're not magicians!*** I really can't tell what's wrong with your code, and we know how much debugging sucks. Start with commenting out most of your code and just `ping` your server to see if you get a response. Then work your way up to the file upload.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with following php code it work perfect.

```
<?php
$file_path = "uploads/";
    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

I have tested it work perfect

Comment: Hi mate, where abouts in the localhost server is the file saved? Like in which directory?

Comment: sorry, updated now, in your php code directory uploads folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using json parser for this, set your PHP script to output json, to get the success and failures. You need to parse the image file name  string from you java code to the web service, and get it to perform the operation. 
You can also use the $_GET to get your file from your java code